# Explanation of the tuple grad_fn.next_functions in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

The torch computation graph is composed of `grad_fn`. For the terminating node, the `grad_fn` object has an attribute called `next_functions` which is a tuple. I understand that using the first element (0th index) of the tuple, I can reconstruct the computation graph for gradients. But I was wondering what does the second element (1st index) of the tuple mean?

In [one of the answers](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/in-the-grad-fn-i-find-a-next-functions-but-i-dont-understand-the-meaning-of-the-attribute/24463/3) in PyTorch forums, it is said that:

> The number is the input number to the next backward function, so can only be non-zero when a function has multiple differentiable outputs (there aren’t that many, but e.g. the RNN functions typically do).

But I am don't understand this statement. Can someone explain this with an example perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on Pytorch, but trying to answer your question, from the example:

```py
a, b = torch.randn(2, requires_grad=True).unbind()
c = a+b
print(c.grad_fn.next_functions)
>>> ((<UnbindBackward object at 0x7f0ea438de80>, 0), (<UnbindBackward object at 0x7f0ea438de80>, 1))
```

Now, think of any Pytorch function as producing "a list of outputs", rather than "an output". So, if a function produces just one output (typical case); it produces a list that is equal to `[output]`. However, if the function produces several outputs, then it has a list of len > 1 outputs, eg: [output0, output1].
From that, I understand the tuple constituents as follows:
`(grad_fn: the function object that resulted in this tensor, i: index of the tensor in the function outputs list.. which is typically zero since functions typically have one output)`

Applying this understanding on the code, the `unbind` function has two outputs: `a` at index `0` of the outputs 'list', and `b` at index `1` of the outputs 'list'. The following points reason through the graph:

- `c.grad_fn` is an `AddBackward` object, since `c` is the result of an addition operation. That addition operation has two branches in the computational graph (since it adds two operands, `a` and `b`). The first branch is for `a` and the second branch is for `b`(one branch for the operands, in order).
- lets say `output_tuple = c.grad_fun.next_functions`, `output_tuple` has 2 elements, `output_tuple[0]` is `a`'s (`grad_fn`, index of `a` in unbind outputs), and `output_tuple[1]` is for `b`'s (`grad_fn`, index of `b` in unbind outputs).
- `a`'s grad_fn and b's grad_fn are the same (i.e. same exact object, `a.grad_fn == b.grad_fn` return True). However, `a`'s tuple has the second element = **0** since it is the **first** output of the unbind function and `b`'s tuple has the second element = **1** since it is the **second** output of the unbind function.

i.e. the second entry in the grad_fn tuple is the index of the tensor in the producing-function list of outputs.